# Apache CloudStack: No templates showing when adding instance

Tags: centos, nfs, kvm, apache-cloudstack

I have setup the apache cloudstack on CentOS 6.8 machine following [quick installation guide](http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/projects/cloudstack-installation/en/4.9/qig.html). The management server and KVM are setup on the same machine. The management server is running without problems. I was able to add zone, pod, cluster, primary and secondary storage from the web interface. But when I tried to add an instance it is not showing any templates in the second stage as you can see in the screenshot
[image]

However, I am able to see two templates under `Templates` link in web UI. 
[image]

But when I select the template and navigate to `Zone` tab, I see `Timeout waiting for response from storage host` and `Ready` field shows no.

[image]

When I check the management server logs, it seems there is an error when cloudstack tries to mount secondary storage for use. The below segment from cloudstack-management.log file describes this error.

```
    2017-03-09 23:26:43,207 DEBUG [c.c.a.t.Request] (AgentManager-Handler-
14:null) (logid:) Seq 2-7686800138991304712: Processing:  { Ans: , MgmtId: 
279278805450918, via: 2, Ver: v1, Flags: 10, [{"com.cloud.agent.api.Answer":
{"result":false,"details":"com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: 
GetRootDir for nfs://172.16.10.2/export/secondary failed due to 
com.cloud.utils.exception.CloudRuntimeException: Unable to mount 
172.16.10.2:/export/secondary at /mnt/SecStorage/6e26529d-c659-3053-8acb-
817a77b6cfc6 due to mount.nfs: Connection timed out\n\tat 
org.apache.cloudstack.storage.resource.NfsSecondaryStorageResource.getRootDir(Nf
sSecondaryStorageResource.java:2080)\n\tat 
org.apache.cloudstack.storage.resource.NfsSecondaryStorageResource.execute(NfsSe
condaryStorageResource.java:1829)\n\tat 
org.apache.cloudstack.storage.resource.NfsSecondaryStorageResource.executeReques
t(NfsSecondaryStorageResource.java:265)\n\tat 
com.cloud.agent.Agent.processRequest(Agent.java:525)\n\tat 
com.cloud.agent.Agent$AgentRequestHandler.doTask(Agent.java:833)\n\tat 
com.cloud.utils.nio.Task.call(Task.java:83)\n\tat 
com.cloud.utils.nio.Task.call(Task.java:29)\n\tat 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)\n\tat 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)\
n\tat 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)\
n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n","wait":0}}] }
```

Can anyone please guide me how to resolve this issue? I have been trying to figure it out for some hours now and don't know how to proceed further.
**Edit 1:** Please note that my LAN address was `10.103.72.50` which I assume is not `/24` address. I tried to give CentOs a static IP by making the following settings in `ifcg-eth0` file

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=52:54:00:B9:A6:C0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=172.16.10.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=172.16.10.1
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
```

But doing this would stop my internet. As a workaround, I reverted these changes and installed all the packages first. Then I changed the IP to static by the same configuration settings as above and ran the cloudstack management. Everything worked fine untill I bumped into this template thing. Please help me figure out what might have went wrong

Comment: Due to the problem mentioned in `Edit 1` my system is unable to reach the internet.  Is it necessary for the system to find internet for correct functioning?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but for people trying out in the future, here it goes:
I hope you have successfully added a host as mentioned in Quick Install Guide before you changed your IP to static as it autoconfigures VLANs for different traffic and creates two bridges - generally with names 'cloud' or 'cloudbr'. Cloudstack uses the Secondary Storage System VM for doing all the storage-related operations in each Zone and Cluster. What seems to be the problem is that secondary storage system vm (SSVM) is not able to communicate with the management server at port 8250. If not, try manually mounting the NFS server's mount points in the SSVM shell. You can ssh into the SSVM using the below command:

```
ssh -i  /var/cloudstack/management/.ssh/id_rsa  -p 3922 root@<Private or Link local Ip address of SSVM>
```

I suggest you run the `/usr/local/cloud/systemvm/ssvm-check.sh` after doing ssh into the secondary storage system VM (assuming it is running) and has it's private, public and link local IP address. If that doesn't help you much, take a look at the [secondary storage troubleshooting docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CLOUDSTACK/SSVM%2C+templates%2C+Secondary+storage+troubleshooting) at Cloudstack.

I would further recommend, if anyone in future runs into similar issues, check if the SSVM is running and is in "Up" state in the System VMs section of Infrastructure tab and that you are able to open up a console session of it from the browser. If that is working go on to run the ssvm-check.sh script mentioned above which systematically checks each and every point of operation that SSVM executes. Even if console session cannot be opened up, you can still ssh using the link local IP address of SSVM which can be accessed by opening up details of SSVM and than execute the script. If it says, it cannot communicate with Management Server at port 8250, I recommend you check the iptables rules of management server and make sure all traffic is allowed at port 8250. A custom command to check the same is `nc -v <mngmnt-server-ip> 8250`. You can do a simple search and learn how to add port 8250 in your iptables rules if that is not opened. Next, you mentioned you used CentOS 6.8, so it probably uses older versions of nfs, so execute `exportfs -a` in your NFS server to make sure all the NFS shares are properly exported and there are no errors. I would recommend that you wait for the downloading status of CentOS 5.5 no GUI kvm template to be complete and its Ready status shown as 'Yes' before you start importing your own templates and ISOs to execute on VMs. Finally, if your ssvm-check.sh script shows everything is good and the download still does not start, you can run the command: `service cloud restart` and actually check if the service has gotten a PID using `service cloud status` as the older versions of system vm templates sometimes need us to manually start the cloud service using `service cloud start` even after the restart command. Restarting the cloud service in SSVM triggers the restart of downloading of all remaining templates and ISOs. Side note: the system VMs uses a Debian kernel if you want to do some more troubleshooting. Hope this helps.